# How to install ROS on Ubuntu 16 running on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 16 can be installed on a Raspberry Pi as [documented here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi).

ROS can be installed on Ubuntu 16, as [documented here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu).

ROS has also be successfully installed on ARM versions of Ubuntu in the past, as [documented here](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/UbuntuARM).

How do you install the current Kinetic on Ubuntu ARM?

I've installed a 16.04 image on a Raspberry Pi 3 without issue, but when I try to follow the [Kinetic install instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/UbuntuARM), they completely fail at the install of `ros-kinetic-ros-base`. Python seems to be corrupt somehow, and I get a ton of errors about "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of..."

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238056/how-to-install-ros-on-ubuntu-16-running-on-a-raspberry-pi/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue, I switched to the [shadow-fix](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) repositories and it fixed it.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2016-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0